# how to pass list input to aws vpc elb in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

here i'm trying to provision a aws classic ELB in a VPC where i have 2 public subnets. These subnets are also provisioned by terraform and i'm trying to pass both the subnets ids to elb module.SO the problem is i'm not able to give list input to elb subnets field

public_subnet variable works fine as i have used it for route table association it's just that i'm not able to handle the list and give it as input to vpc.

it works if i use subnets = [var.public_subnet.0,var.public_subnet.1]

here's my code

````
resource "aws_elb" "webelb" {
  name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
  #availability_zones = [var.public_subnet]
  subnets = [var.public_subnet]
#
#
#
}

variable "public_subnet" {
  type = list
}

subnet.tf
output "public_subnet" {
  value = aws_subnet.public.*.id
}```

Error:
```Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on elb/elb.tf line 4, in resource "aws_elb" "webelb":
   4:   availability_zones = [var.public_subnet]

Inappropriate value for attribute "availability_zones": element 0: string
required.```
````

Comment: does it work if you just pass ```subnets = var.public_subnet``` . It's helpful to give the terraform version because the syntax changed, also showing the actual source of the subnets would be useful to. (ps I'd suggest changing your var to public_subnets, plural, if it's holding an array)

Comment: thanks to @Datise  that worked as expected

Comment: I'm going to answer if you can accept it that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `var.public_subnet` is already a list. `[var.public_subnet]` is equivalent to `[["192.168.0.0/32"]]` instead of the expected, un-nested input `["102.168.0.0/32"]`

ie...just use `var.public_subnet`